# How can i get a client side cookie with next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, jwt, next.js

I can't find a way to get a constant value of isAuthenticated variable across both server and client side with next.js

I am using a custom app.js to wrap the app within the Apollo Provider. I am using the layout to display if the user is authenticated or not. The defaultPage is a HOC component.

When a page is server side, isAuthenticated is set a true. But as soon as I change page - which are client side rendering (no reload) - the isAuthenticated remain at undefined all the way long until I reload the page.

_app.js

```js
import App from 'next/app';
import React from 'react';
import withData from '../lib/apollo';
import Layout from '../components/layout';

class MyApp extends App {
    // static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    //     let pageProps = {};
    //     if (Component.getInitialProps) {
    //       pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    //     }
    //     return { pageProps };
    //   }

    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps, isAuthenticated } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <Layout isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} {...pageProps}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Layout>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withData(MyApp);
```

layout.js

```js
import React from "react";
import defaultPage from "../hoc/defaultPage";

class Layout extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
      let pageProps = {};
      if (Component.getInitialProps) {
        pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
      }

      return { pageProps, isAuthenticated };
    }
    render() {
      const { isAuthenticated, children } = this.props;
      return (
          <div>
              {isAuthenticated ? (
                  <h2>I am logged</h2>
              ) : (
                    <h2>I am not logged</h2>
              )}
                {children}
            </div>
      )
    }
}

export default defaultPage(Layout);
```

defaultPage.js

```js
/* hocs/defaultPage.js */

import React from "react";
import Router from "next/router";

import Auth from "../components/auth";
const auth = new Auth();

export default Page =>

  class DefaultPage extends React.Component {

    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {

      const loggedUser = process.browser
        ? auth.getUserFromLocalCookie()
        : auth.getUserFromServerCookie(ctx);

      const pageProps = Page.getInitialProps && Page.getInitialProps(ctx);

      let path = ""
      return {
        ...pageProps,
        loggedUser,
        currentUrl: path,
        isAuthenticated: !!loggedUser
      };
    }

    render() {
      return <Page {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Make sure you've changed fetch policy to network-only in Apollo. Maybe it's trying to read from cache. I had the same problem not long ago. Also, maybe you will have to write to cache manually after you login.

Answer (score -1):

I think client side and server side are not use the same cookie. So here is how you get client side cookie and you have to attach this cookie in your server side request.

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    // this is client side cookie that you want
    const cookie = ctx.req ? ctx.req.headers.cookie : null

    // and if you use fetch, you can manually attach cookie like this
    fetch('is-authenticated', {
        headers: {
            cookie
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With NextJs you can get client aide cookie without any extra library, but what I'll encourage you to do is install 
[js-cookie](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie&ved=2ahUKEwjw-92PksbwAhVqQkEAHQUFC4AQFjAAegQIAxAC&usg=AOvVaw1Vb_gDvAUfpq9nc9G0oL3V)

```
import cookie from "js-cookie"

 export default () => {
   //to get a particular cookie
    const authCookie = cookies.get("cookieName")

    return "hey"
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({req: {headers: {cookie}} => {
    console.log(cookie)

       return {
        props: {key: "whatever you want to return"
    }
}
```

Its been long, I used class components, but you get the concept in case you'll need a class component